# Почему не работает сертификат CloudFlare

Tags: сертификат

Я решил создать бесплатный сертификат для своего сайта на CloudFlare. В общем-то все получилось, но проблема в следующем. Сам я проживаю в Узбекистане и для выхода в интернет обычно пользуюсь VPN. Поэтому поначалу даже не заметил, что имеется проблема, то есть сертификат заработал и соединенное получилось защищенным. Но потом я отключил VPN и зайти на свой сайт не удалось совсем (пишет, что сайт может представлять угрозу). Пробовал менять ip на американские, европейские, российские - все идеально, подключение защищено. Но с узбекским ip либо не могу зайти вовсе, либо, если и заходит, то соединение получается незащищенным. Есть ли тут кто-нибудь, у кого возникала подобная проблема?

Answer (score 0):

В браузере нажми на замочек, там на сертификат и сравни подпись с тем сертификатом, что получил на клаудфларе. Сравни "Общее название" с тем что в адресной строке.

Comment: Все совпадает: Review Universal Certificate for *.mysite.ru, mysite.ru